Webcam Works With Cheese But Not In Firefox Browser
Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate (usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.5):
/dev/video1
/dev/video2
/dev/media0
This is the webcam I use for cheese and it works.
However, when I try to use it in Firefox, for example, discord, it says no video devices. I need to use it for a separate proctoring web application which also does not recognize that I have a web camera.So basically it seems like Firefox cannot recognize that I have a camera. Any advice on how to fix this?
uname -a
Linux iamjedi322-Inspiron-5748 6.5.0-28-generic #29~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  4 14:39:20 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
I have not found much useful information about this problem on the web.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
